# Sending back a JSON response when failing Passport.js authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I'm using `Node.js` as a backend API server for an iPhone client.  I'm using `Passport.js` to authenticate with a `local strategy`.  The relevant code is below:

```
// This is in user.js, my user model
UserSchema.static('authenticate', function(username, password, callback) {
    this.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err){
            console.log('findOne error occurred');
            return callback(err);
        }
        if (!user){
            return callback(null, false);
        }
        user.verifyPassword(password, function(err, passwordCorrect){
            if (err){
                console.log('verifyPassword error occurred');
                return callback(err);
            }
            if (!passwordCorrect){
                console.log('Wrong password');
                return callback(err, false);
            }
            console.log('User Found, returning user');
            return callback(null, user);
        });
    });
});
```

and

```
// This is in app.js
app.get('/loginfail', function(req, res){
    res.json(403, {message: 'Invalid username/password'});
});

app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/loginfail', failureFlash: false }),
    function(req, res) {
       res.redirect('/');
});
```

Right now, I have managed to redirect a failed login to /loginfail, where I send back some JSON to the iPhone client.  However, this doesn't have enough granularity.  I want to be able to send back the appropriate errors to the iPhone client, such as: "No user found" or "Password is wrong".  With my existing code, I don't see how this can be accomplished.

I tried to follow the examples for a custom callback on the passport.js site, but I just can't get it to work due to lack of node understanding.  How could I modify my code so that I'd be able to send back a res.json with an appropriate error code/message?

I am trying something like this now:

```
// In app.js
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        if (!user) {
            console.log(info);
            // *** Display message without using flash option
            // re-render the login form with a message
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }
        console.log('got user');
        return res.json(200, {user_id: user._id});
    })(req, res, next);
});

// In user.js
UserSchema.static('authenticate', function(username, password, callback) {
    this.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err){
            console.log('findOne error occurred');
            return callback(err);
        }
        if (!user){
            return callback(null, false);
        }
        user.verifyPassword(password, function(err, passwordCorrect){
            if (err){
                return callback(err);
            }
            if (!passwordCorrect){
                return callback(err, false, {message: 'bad password'});
            }
            console.log('User Found, returning user');
            return callback(null, user);
        });
    });
});
```

But back when I try to console.log(info), it just says undefined.  I don't know how to get this custom callback working...Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I also tripped in this problem for a while. Your solution is similar to [custom callback](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/#custom-callback) from Passport.js doc

Comment: custom callback makes it your responsibility to establish a session. if you wish to avoid it, I found a workaround by emulating the flash message mechanism (See below)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe the callback function that your 'authenticate' static calls (called 'callback' in your code) accepts a 3rd parameter - "info" - which your code can provide. Then, instead of passing in the { failureRedirect: ...} object, pass in a function which takes 3 arguments - err, user, and info. The "info" you provided in your authenticate method will be passed to this callback.

Passport calls this scenario "custom callback".  See the docs here:
http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/

Comment: Thank you for this.  I am aware of the custom callback, but my problem is I just don't understand how to implement it (sorry very new to node and js).  I have edited my question with my latest efforts.  As you can see, I am trying to use this "info" parameter, but I don't know how to correctly use it -- it is always undefined when I get back from authentication.

Comment: Sorry, I just figured out that I needed to add "info" to this as well:

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
        User.authenticate(username, password, function(err, user, info) {
            return done(err, user, info);
        });
    }
));

Comment: This conversation helped me come to the same conclusion with a little more substance. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/255

Comment: @kurisukun Why have you passed (req, res, next) in passport.authenticate?

Comment: For the future, could you add a couple of code snippets to clarify? This is somewhat hard to parse without it.

Answer (score 79):

I had a similar issue with `Passport` and failed login responses. I was building an API, and wanted all responses to be returned as `JSON`. Passport responds to an invalid password with status: `401` and body: `Unauthorized`. **That's just a text string in the body, not JSON, so it broke my client which expected all JSON.**

As it turns out, there is a way to make Passport just return the error to the framework instead of trying to send a response itself.

The answer is to set `failWithError` in the options passed to authenticate:
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/126#issuecomment-32333163

From jaredhanson's comment in the issue:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { failWithError: true }),
  function(req, res, next) {
    // handle success
    if (req.xhr) { return res.json({ id: req.user.id }); }
    return res.redirect('/');
  },
  function(err, req, res, next) {
    // handle error
    if (req.xhr) { return res.json(err); }
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }
);
```

This will invoke the error handler after Passport calls `next(err)`. For my app, I wrote a generic error handler specific to my use case of just providing a JSON error:

```
// Middleware error handler for json response
function handleError(err,req,res,next){
    var output = {
        error: {
            name: err.name,
            message: err.message,
            text: err.toString()
        }
    };
    var statusCode = err.status || 500;
    res.status(statusCode).json(output);
}
```

Then I used it for all api routes:

```
var api = express.Router();
...
//set up some routes here, attached to api
...
// error handling middleware last
api.use( [
        handleError
        ] );
```

I didn't find the `failWithError` option in the documentation. I stumbled upon it while tracing through the code in the debugger.

Also, before I figured this out, I tried the "custom callback" mentioned in the @Kevin_Dente answer, but it didn't work for me. I'm not sure if that was for an older version of Passport or if I was just doing it wrong.

Comment: still valid in 2017 LOL

Comment: still valid. :P

Comment: still valid in 2021

Answer (score 11):

There is an official documentation for **Custom Callback**:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

https://github.com/passport/www.passportjs.org/blob/master/views/docs/authenticate.md

Answer (score 3):

You can do that without custom callbacks using property `passReqToCallback` in your strategy definition:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({passReqToCallback: true}, validateUserPassword));
```

Then you can add your custom auth error code to the request in your strategy code:

```
var validateUserPassword = function (req, username, password, done) {
    userService.findUser(username)
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                req.authError = "UserNotFound";
                return done(null, false);
            }
```

And finally you can handle these custom errors in your route:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failWithError: true })      
    function (req, res) {
        ....
    }, function(err, req, res, next) {
        if(req.autherror) {
            res.status(401).send(req.autherror)
        } else {
            ....
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the official documentation of `Passport` you may use [custom callback](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/#custom-callback) function to handle the case of failed authorization and override the default message.

If you are developing REST API and then you would want to send out pretty JSON response something as below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "JsonWebTokenError",
        "message": "invalid signature"
    },
    "message": "You are not authorized to access this protected resource",
    "statusCode": 401,
    "data": [],
    "success": false
}
```

I was using `Passport JWT` authentication to secure some of my routes and was applied the `authMiddleware` as below:

**app/middlewares/authMiddleware.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const _ = require('lodash');

router.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {

    // If authentication failed, `user` will be set to false. If an exception occurred, `err` will be set.
    if (err || !user || _.isEmpty(user)) {
      // PASS THE ERROR OBJECT TO THE NEXT ROUTE i.e THE APP'S COMMON ERROR HANDLING MIDDLEWARE
      return next(info);
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app/routes/approutes.js**

```
const authMiddleware = require('../middlewares/authMiddleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
  // secure the route by applying authentication middleware
  app.use('/users', authMiddleware);
  .....
  ...
  ..

  // ERROR-HANDLING MIDDLEWARE FOR SENDING ERROR RESPONSES TO MAINTAIN A CONSISTENT FORMAT
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    let responseStatusCode = 500;
    let responseObj = {
      success: false,
      data: [],
      error: err,
      message: 'There was some internal server error',
    };

    // IF THERE WAS SOME ERROR THROWN BY PREVIOUS REQUEST
    if (!_.isNil(err)) {
      // IF THE ERROR IS REALTED TO JWT AUTHENTICATE, SET STATUS CODE TO 401 AND SET A CUSTOM MESSAGE FOR UNAUTHORIZED
      if (err.name === 'JsonWebTokenError') {
        responseStatusCode = 401;
        responseObj.message = 'You are not authorized to access this protected resource';
      }
    }

    if (!res.headersSent) {
      res.status(responseStatusCode).json(responseObj);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

A short workaround is to emulate the Flash method call which intended originally to support connect-flash and to use this method to return the JSON object.

first define the "emulator":

```
var emulateFlash = function (req, res, next) {
        req.flash = (type, message) => {
            return res.status(403).send({ status: "fail", message });
        }
        next();
    }
```

this will inject the flash method which will send the error JSON object upon failure.

In the route do the following:

1st, use the emulator across the board using:

```
router.use(emulateFlash);
```

One can instead use the emulateFlash method on each route needed.

2nd, on the route when using authenticate, specify the failureFlash option using a message:

```
router.route("/signin")
    .post(.authenticate('local', { session: false,  failureFlash: "Invalid email or password."}), UsersController.signIn);
```

I tested this for both failed authentication as well as successful and found it working. Looking at the code I could not find any other way to return an object other than implementing the callback method which requires much more work.