# Passport.js : How can I change passport's default unauthorized response to my custom response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js, ejs

**I have this: **
The project is in NodeJS, Express, MongoDB

```
passport.use(
    "local-login",
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: "email",
        passwordField: "password",
        passReqToCallback: true, // adăugați această opțiune pentru a transmite obiectul "req" în cadrul funcției de verificare a parolei
      },
      async (req,email, password, done) => { // adăugați și obiectul "req" ca prim parametru în funcția de verificare a parolei
        try {
          const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
          if (!user) return done(null, false,{ message: 'Incorrect username or password.' });
          const isMatch = await user.matchPassword(password);
          if (!isMatch){
            req.flash("error", "Parola introdusă este incorectă.");
            return done(null, false);
          }
          // check if user is admin
          if (user.role === "admin") {
          user.isAdmin = true;
          }
  
          // setați proprietatea "user" în obiectul "req.session"
          req.session.user = user;
          return done(null, user);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return done(error, false);
        }
      }
    )
  );
```

and this:

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local-login", {failureMessage: true}), async (req, res, next) => {
  const comenzi = await Comanda.find({ utilizator: req.user.username }).sort({ createdAt: 'desc' });

  // set cookie
  res.cookie("user", req.user, { maxAge: 3600000, httpOnly: true, secure: false });
  

  // login
  jwt.sign(
    { user: req.user },
    "secretKey",
    { expiresIn: "1h" },
    (err, token) => {
      if (err) {
        req.flash("error", "Failed to login");
        return res.redirect("/login");
      }
      res.render("login", { user: req.user, messages: req.flash(), comenzi: comenzi });
    }
  );
});
```

And I don't know how I can put a error message in html I use EJS for front-end
When I try to login and the pass or user is wrong to say something in front not a blackscreen with Unauthorized

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending back a JSON response when failing Passport.js authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388206/sending-back-a-json-response-when-failing-passport-js-authentication)